# Closing a Panda3d app without shutting down the whole Process

Tags: python, python-2.7, panda3d

wrote a small application which is composed of a QT GUI module which in turn initiate an object that inherits from ShowBase class.

Problem is, if I close the Panda App, the ShowBase class calls finalizeExit() which in turn shuts the whole process by calling exit.

If I avoid calling the finalize method by overriding userExit(), the resources for the App are not being deleted and the task manager keeps on working.

Is there a way to close the Panda App without calling exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in recent development builds of Panda, you should be able to call `base.destroy()` to shut down ShowBase and unload (most) resources.  You would still need to override `finalizeExit()` to not quit the application when the main window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer comes very late but it might help others. 
I had the same problem but with Tkinter not QT.

what you can do is after you call your application's class:

```
app = my_class(...)

try: app.run()
except SystemExit: base.destroy()
```

this controls how panda closes the app. in this case it will not call finalizeExit() at all. base.destroy() will destroy the opened windows.